# ec2 instance running continually

Tags: amazon-ec2

just wondering is it possible that I can run an instance after I disconnect it?
The only thing I found is the link but it is not relevant to what I want.
[link1](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-okay-to-continuously-run-an-AWS-EC2-instance)
[link2](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/getting-started/tutorials/remotely-run-commands-ec2-instance-systems-manager/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean keep it running in background?try

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Comment: mank thanks, this one works